# Sorting PHP array without ksort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ksort

I am trying to manually sort a PHP array without making use of ksort.

This is how my code looks at the moment:

```
function my_ksort(&$arg){
    foreach($arg as $key1 => $value1){
      foreach($arg as $key2 => $value2){
        if($key1 > $key2){
          $aux = $value2;
          $arg[$key2] = $value1;
          $arg[$key1] = $aux;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

It doesn't sort, I can't figure out how to make it sort.

Comment: ... and? What's your question?

Comment: and why exactly do oyu have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You have a syntax error. Too many `}`s

Comment: Its for learning purposes I am not trying to "reinvent the wheel". I need to know how to switch elements in the array to sort by keys.

Comment: The `$keyX` variables you're creating are just copies of what's in the $arg array. Changing their values inside the loop does NOT affect the array in any way.

Comment: @MarcB sorry, I copied an older version. I actually am using the array variable $arg to switch the elements.

Comment: Do you want to sort in ASC ?

Comment: Yes, ascending. This is not an issue, just changing the sign?

Comment: This is ksort implemented in JS, could give you an idea of how its coded: http://phpjs.org/functions/ksort/. This also includes the sort flags PHP provides.

Comment: You're not relocating elements, you're just altering the key/value association.

Comment: Are you willing to use any other sort function in the process, or are they all out of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function my_ksort(&$arg)
    {
    $keys=array_keys($arg);
    sort($keys);
    foreach($keys as $key)
        {
        $val=$arg[$key];
        unset($arg[$key]);
        $arg[$key]=$val;
        }
    }
```

I'm sorting the keys separately and then deleting the elements one-by-one and appending them to the end, in ascending order.

I'm using another sorting function (`sort()`), but if you want to eliminate all available sorting functions from your emulation, `sort()` is much easier to emulate. In fact, [@crypticous's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302695/2718747) does just that!

Answer (score 0):

This function return array in ASC. Take in consideration that I'm using [goto](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) which is supported in `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)`

```
function ascending_array($array){
    if (!is_array($array)){
        $array = explode(",", $array);
    }

    $new = array();
    $flag = true;

    iter:
        $array = array_values($array); // recount array values with new offsets

        (isset($min["max"])) ? $min["value"] = $min["max"] : $min["value"] = $array[0];
        $min["offset"] = 0;

        for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
            if ($array[$i] < $min["value"]){ // redefine min values each time if statement executed
                $min["value"] = $array[$i];
                $min["offset"] = $i;
            }

            if ($flag){ // execute only first time
                if ($array[$i] > $min["value"]){ // define max value from array
                    $min["max"] = $array[$i];
                }
                $flag = false;
            }

            if ($i === (count($array)-1)){ // last array element
                array_push($new,$min["value"]);
                unset($array[$min["offset"]]);
            }
        }

    if (count($array)!=0){
        goto iter;
    }
    print_r($new);
}

$arr = array(50,25,98,45);

ascending_array($arr); // 25 45 50 98
```

**PS.** When I was studying `php`, I wrote this function and now remembered that I had it (that's why I really don't remember what I am doing in it, though fact is it's working properly and hopefully there are comments too), hope you'll enjoy :)

<kbd>[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mkd-yfc)</kbd>

Comment: The usage of `goto` is a terrible practice. Even the [manual page](http://php.net/goto) says so. Are you sure there is no other alternatives? Like `do/while` ?

Comment: Am I missing something or this has _nothing to do with `ksort()`_?

Comment: Alternatives are always in everything, just like you see I've written this code a long time ago, so I really don't going to start it from scratch. For studying and realizing purposes it is good I think

Comment: @geomagas I've asked OP if he wanted `ASC` array function, and he answered YES, so I did post. Any problems ?

Comment: Yes, `ksort()` sorts according to _keys_, yours doesn't. ASC or DESC is irrelevant.

Comment: @geomagas Yes, it isn't sorting with keys, anyways hope OP find it interesting

Comment: @crypticous Your code sorts the array by values and deletes the keys.  I am trying to sort the keys and preserve the values.  Nonetheless thank you.

Comment: @crypticous: I do find it too (especially `goto` - I hadn't seen _that_ for so many years). It's just that it's an answer to _another question_ and not the one at hand.

Comment: @DragoslavPaul Yes, it's sorting with values (not with keys)

Comment: @geomagas Maybe, I just wanted to help, that's all, anyways if it is any problem I'll delete it

Comment: @DragoslavPaul Anyways I think you can copy that practice and do it with your own (try to change `goto` as well)

Comment: @crypticous: No don't. In fact, I'm planning to link my answer to yours! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was checking some issue related to this post and i wanted to give my insight about it ! here's what i would have done to implement php's sort :

```
$array_res = array();
$array = array(50,25,98,45);
$i=0;

 $temp = $array[0];
 $key = array_search($temp, $array);
while ($i<count($array)-1){

     $temp = $array[0];
    for($n=0;$n<count($array) ;$n++)
    {

        if($array[$n]< $temp && $array[$n] != -1 )
        {

             $temp = $array[$n];

        }
        else{continue;}
    }
//get the index for later deletion
$key = array_search($temp, $array);



array_push($array_res, $temp);
/// flag on those which were ordered
$array[$key] =-1;

$i++;
}

// lastly append the highest number 

for($n=0;$n<count($array) ;$n++)
        {
            if ($array[$n] != -1)

            array_push($array_res, $array[$n]);

        }
// display the results
print_r($array_res);
```

This code will display : Array
(
    [0] => 25
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 50
    [3] => 98
)

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet

```
function custom_ksort($arg)
{
    $keys = array_keys($arg);

    sort($keys);

    foreach($keys as $newV)
    {
        $newArr[$newV] = $arg[$newV];
    }

    return $newArr;
}
```